# confluence4r add

Tags: ruby, confluence

We use Jira/Confluence as our wiki site.  I've had a difficult time trying to figure out how to use the add.  I'm guessing i'm missing something very obvious.  When I go to this site: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DISC/Confluence4r to download the confluence4r file, not sure what I'm supposed to do thereafter.  The file contains a module which makes sense why it doesn't do anything when running it.  But should I being using the gem install functionality in some way?  When I simply try to use it in a ruby script, i get the following error:

```
conf.rb:15:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Confluence (NameError)
```

Where I am supplying the information required per the script (URL, user & pass contained the correct values when used):

```
server = Confluence::Server.new("https://collab.sitename.com")
server.login("user", "pass")
puts server.getSpaces()
```

Any information how to get the working is appreciated.

Comment: Did you require the file with the Confluence module - `require 'confluence4r'`?

Comment: Yes, tried that too. C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require':
cannot load such file -- confluence4r.rb (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
n `require'
        from C:/MM/ruby/conf.rb:4:in `<main>'

Comment: I installed the confluence & confluence-client ruby gems.  I'm not sure how to go about installing the confluence4r gem, if that is what is required.  Just getting started with this stuff...ruby, watir, etc..  :)

Answer (score 0):

Confluence4r isn't distributed as a rubygem, it's just a ruby script you can drop onto your filesystem and reference directly.

If you put Confluence4r.rb in the same directory as your own script, you'd need to require it like this:

```
require './confluence4r.rb'
```

You shouldn't need the "confluence" and "confluence-client" rubygems to use confluence4r; it's just a very thin wrapper around the Confluence XML-RPC API.